# Passing state-based data between pages in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a multiple page form in React, and I have the basic wireframe set up.  I am trying to export a user's Name from one page to the next, but the user will change depending on who has logged in.  I've been in google purgatory for a while trying figure out how to grab a specific state-based value out of a component to be available on another page. In my code below, I'm exporting the whole component to render on the App.js page.  However, I'd also like to grab just the `{userName}` to render within another component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Intro extends Component {
    state = { userName: ''}

    handleChange = (event) => this.setState({ userName: event.target.value })


    render() {
        const { userName } = this.state

        return (
            <div id='intro'>
                <form>
                    <FieldGroup
                        id='nameArea'
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}

                    />

                    <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit' /> . 
                  </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Intro
```

Comment: I think you can have parent component where you can handle the state and share it within the pages(Child Components).

Comment: Where do you store logged in user information currently? In local storage, or in local state of App.js? It is mentioned that, the userName will change depending on logged in user, however, in the code it looks like there is an input field that controls the userName

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, you can't. This is where tools like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) come into play. Here's an example using React's new [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

```
const UserContext = React.createContext('');

class Intro extends Component {

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.props.updateUserName(event.target.value);
  }


  render() {
    const { userName } = this.props

    return (
      <div id='intro'>
        <form>
          <input
            id='nameArea'
            value={userName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />

          <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit' /> .
                  </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// only doing this to shield end-users from the
// implementation detail of "context"
const UserConsumer = UserContext.Consumer

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { userName: '' }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={this.state.userName}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Intro userName={this.state.userName} updateUserName={(userName) => this.setState({userName})} />
          <UserConsumer>
            {user => <div>Username: {JSON.stringify(user)}</div>}
          </UserConsumer>
        </React.Fragment>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

See my updated codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9226pkn94).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful!

Comment: just a side note, above example is not a sample for redux. It is using React context instead. From your initial sentence it sounds like the example below is how you do it with redux.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when you need data on another component, the solution is store the date higher in your component.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already said, the most easy way is trying to pass your state via props from your higher order component to the childs. 
Another approach would be to use Redux for your state management. This gives you one global state store accessible from any component.
Third you can try to use the react context api.